# From Existing Apk Regenrate new Dynamic Apk

Tags: android, apk

Suppose on site i have one apk with there online JSON Data of site, now depend on that apk i want to regenerate new apk file with new JSON data,
as well as need to application icon from Manifest file also dynamically change, and package name also dynamically rename,Resource icon should dynamic change  and want to put it on site dynamically.

how its possible ?

thaks in advance.

Comment: You could try the steps I outlined in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418841/app-inventor-install-apps-onto-sd-card). Ofcourse, you will need to automate the decompilation and recompilation of the apk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ant/maven or whatever build tool you chose and then do:

1)create package for first your activity, It will be application package name, all other activities will be in different package(not the sub package of current one)

2) use regex task (I do know ant and maven have such) to replace package name in manifest and package name in your first activity
2.1) use copy task to copy first activity into new package directory

3) now we need to copy different icon's and url's for json data. use copy task to copy new 
image for current config. I suggest create folders structure config/{config_name}/drawable/icon.png and config/{config_name}/values/config.xml (config.xml is android resource file with some kind of json_data_url resource)
then for custom copy task you will have different json data and application icon.

4) create switch config task, which will call 2nd and 3rd to do what you want with application

Comment: I didn't realize the ant tool could script. Do you have any good resources for learning the extent of things it can do?

Comment: for this particular tasks http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual//Tasks/replaceregexp.html

Comment: and in general http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html and http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html comes with android sdk. Perhaps there are more different extensions, but I did not used them.

Comment: And if you have sophisticated scripting, do not use ant. Better go with python. Here the case was simple.

Comment: I need to consistently change the package names of all the java files, change the package names in the manifest file, change some xml color fields in two layout files, and change some drawable resources. Ant can do all that?

Comment: Why all the java files?
I suggest packages my.fake.package1.Activity and start app from it, all other activities in my.original.package. And you can easy change color's or just copy custom-colors.xml file from different configs and link color in layout via @color/custom_color

Comment: I think that ant is overhead when I need to do programming in it, like for loops, or if statement. Ant is ok when things work by linear algorithm.

Comment: I know how to do do it manually, but I will need to do this for potentially hundreds of apps to push out quick updates of a similar code base

Comment: if you can do it by one line command for ant, you can execute these command in shell hundreds times from python script or any other language

Comment: can you look at this new question I asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752650/ant-regex-for-android-package-names