# ant regex for android package names

Tags: android, regex, ant, build-process

in my android project all of my .java view files import the R file based on the name of the current package. When I change the name of my package name in the Android Manifest (dynamically, not refactoring via Eclipse or any other IDE), I need to the references of all my java files to point to the new R file that gets generated

I am making a build script via Ant, but I am not sure what the regular expression convention would look like

The strings that need to be replaced look like this:

`import com.mysite.myapp.R;`

ie.

`import com.sushiroll.california.R`

This is what I have in my ant build script

```
<replaceregexp file="src/*"
           match="import*.R"
           replace="import ${current.package}.R"
           byline="true">
        <fileset dir="src/.">
            <include name="*.java"/>
        </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

where I want to match all strings that say `import` and end in `.R`

and replace it with `import $current.package}.R`

how would I word that for ant regex? the match and replace that I wrote were just guesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group old package name chars before .R

if you know package name

```
    match="import com\.mysite\.myapp\.R;"
```

if you do now know package name, but be prepared to be failed for wrong imports if you import R from different packages

```
    match="import (.*).R;"
```

replace to

`replace="import ${current.package}.R;"`

and the

```
    <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html I usually take a look here

Comment: And I strongly suggest to use base android library with com.mysite.myapp.R which will be used by application with com.sushiroll.california package name. And the application with com.sushiroll.california package name will contain just one start activity. Then you do not need to process all of the files to generate unique package name. Just this start activity and manifest

Comment: This regexp is incorrect, as it will also match `import foo.bar.whateverR`. That's because it misses the \ before the last dot. Also the `;` is missing from it, so it will match `import foo.R.bar` too.

Comment: But... this has the same mistakes as before (dot, semicolon). Except that you have replaced the matched package pattern with a concrete package name, but if the original poster needs that, he doesn't even need regexps.

Comment: why the semicolon need to be replaced? we can just skip it

Comment: I won't know the name of the current package, so I can't use that first match

Comment: I used some of this answer as well as the other

Comment: @tabbykitten: Without the `;` it will match `import foo.Rwhatever` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<replaceregexp
   match="import .+?\.R;"
   replace="import ${current.package}.R;"
   flags="g"
> 
...
```

where `+?` is needed so that it works if you have two imports in a line, and `g` needed so not only one import per file is replaced. Although currently you only have one per file since you replace all of them with the same string, this is the universally correct regexp...

Comment: I used some of this answer as well as the other